# $a^2+b^2+c^2 = d^2+e^2+f^2 = m^2, ad + be = cf$ with $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ all distinct positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the smallest positive integer $m$ such that there exist six distinct positive integers $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ satisfying
>   $$a^2+b^2+c^2 = d^2+e^2+f^2 = m^2\\ ad + be = cf$$
>   or show that this cannot be satisfied using six distinct positive integers, for any $m$.

For example, with $\{a=2,b=11,c=10,d=14,e=2,f=5\}$ we have
$$
2^2+11^2+10^2 = 14^2+2^2+5^2 = 225 = 15^2 \\ 2\cdot 14 + 11\cdot 2 = 10\cdot 5
$$
so this set would work, except that here $e = a = 2$ so they are not all distinct.

Comment: http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Pall_Automorphs_1940.pdf

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1560488_three_square_sums_solution_structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the order you want,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
13 & 34 & 14 \\
26 & 2 & 29
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Your $m=39$

The first rational orthogonal matrix with all entry absolute values distinct has your $m=57$

$$
\frac{1}{57} \;
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
17 & 16 & 52 \\
32 & -47 & 4 \\
44 & 28 & -23 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: OMG, I just found that one about a minute before you edited yours in; we must be using similar software! Plus, you effectively read my mind about what I was going for (no coincidences including the cross product vector). +1 in addition to the solve!